# a web page layout

Tags: html, css

I am build a page,however I meet some layout related probelms,I can not make the div ajust its size(acutally the height) automatically. See the following markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <title>Link one</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            div#middle{
                margin-top: 5px;
                margin-bottom: 5px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="background-color: gray;border: solid 1px red" id="top">
            <h1>Top<h1>
        </div>

        <div style="border: solid 1px blue;min-height: 200px" id="middle">
            <div id="leftmenu" style="float: left;background-color:gray;width: 190px">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=''>Link One</a></li>
                    <li><a href=''>Link Two</a></li>
                <ul>
            </div>

            <div id="content" style="background-color: black;margin-left: 200px">
                I am in Link One
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="background-color: gray" id="foot">
            <hr/>
            <p>Copyright xxx</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note the div whose id is "middle",I have to set its height manually,if not the div below it (div with id "foot")will not displayed below it. The foot div will go to the same line with "middle" div,just remove the "min-height: 200px" of "middle" div for a test.

And since the content is not sure,so I can not set its size manually,I just want to the height of the middle div to be the larger height of "leftmenu" or "content".

Any ideas?

-----------------------------------------[image]

It does not expand ,

Comment: I guess it's just for experimental reasons but you will remove the inline CSS and place it in a separate file, right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clearing your floats. Add this line `<div style="clear:both;"></div>` below the the div with id=content

```
<div style="border: solid 1px blue;min-height: 200px" id="middle">
            <div id="leftmenu" style="float: left;background-color:gray;width: 190px">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href=''>Link One</a></li>
                    <li><a href=''>Link Two</a></li>
                <ul>
            </div>

            <div id="content" style="background-color: black;margin-left: 200px">
                I am in Link One
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both;"></div>
        </div>
```

It does this because of the flow of the page. The flow is the order of the elements on your page. So in your example, your `li` elements are placed one after the other so the first one will appear before the second one on your page. The same applies to all elements, `<a>, <div>, <p>, <img>` and also text. When an element is floated it is taken out of the flow and elements that follow it are pushed up next to it; this way you can have text flowing around an image or links lined up next to each other.

Unfortunately when you float all elements within another element (as you have done with `#leftmenu` and `#content`) the parent element (`#middle`) acts as if it contains nothing because it has no child elements in the flow and acting as if it was essentially empty. By adding a clearing `<div>` we are creating a child element in the flow right below everything else and the parent element can then calculate the correct height.

I hope I explained that well enough.

Comment: Good!  It works now.  Can you tell me more details? I want to know why?

Comment: Yes,clear enougth now. So does that mean the style of float will make the element fly out even its parent elemetn? Since before I thougth like this:I float the "leftmenu" div,but it is still contained in the div "middle",and the "middle" div does not float,it is still within the normal flow of the page,the same as the "foot" div,so the three divs(top,middle,top) should be put vertically one by one....

Comment: The floated element will always be contained in it's parent element, it won't move outside of this. The only difference is the parent div will act as if it's not there. What the foot is trying to do is move up as far as possible and, in this case, that is next to the UL.

Comment: Thanks I got it.:) That's to say the float div will get out of the normal flow of the page,so the "middle" div will not Calculation the size of "leftmenu",just the "content" div,as a result its height will expand according to the height of "content" div?

Answer (score 1):

Use a background-image to fake equal column height.

Check this article:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/

For clearing use this class:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

like this

```
<div style="border: solid 1px blue;min-height: 200px" id="middle" class="clearfix">
```

Answer (score 1):

The `float:left` is causing the issue. You need to insert a clearing element within middle.

eg

```
    <div style="border: solid 1px blue;min-height: 200px" id="middle">
        <div id="leftmenu" style="float: left;background-color:gray;width: 190px">
            <ul>
                <li><a href=''>Link One</a></li>
                <li><a href=''>Link Two</a></li>
            <ul>
        </div>

        <div id="content" style="background-color: black;margin-left: 200px">
            I am in Link One
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/B7tZu/)

Comment: Thanks,your answer are same as Matt Asbury's.  IT works ,thanks.

Comment: @hguser Ah yes, but I beat him to it :)

Comment: @hguser There are times when you may actually want this behaviour, ie for a side menu bar which overlays the divs below it.

Comment: I am sorry,but what does this mean?(I am not Engliser) :(

Comment: @hguser Matt has made a more detailed explanation of what is happening in his post..

Comment: Yes,I saw its replay,detailed enough.:)